# Correct way to free double pointers

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

What is the correct way to free a float ** like below.

e.g. `float ** someArray`

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfDimensions; i++)
    {
        somearray[i] = (float *) malloc(numberOfDimensions * sizeof(float));
    }
```

Comment: Man, you changed your question after receiving 6 answer… That will cause some trouble

Comment: I know, people answered so quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have malloc'ed another round of memory and assigned it to each float pointer in the original array, then you should free them as well beforehand:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < numberOfDimensions; i++)
    free(someArray[i]);

// and free the container array only now

free(someArray);
```

P. s.: [don't cast the return value of malloc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: I changed my question, while you answered, sorry.

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect the new question while you were changing the question. Sorry. :P

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're expected to free the elements, and then free the array.

Answer (score 1):

Go backwards:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfDimensions; i++)
{
    free(somearray[i]);
}

free(somearray);
```

Comment: An equal and opposite reaction, got it. ;)

Comment: @Helium3 the approach generalizes to arbitrary dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this case you simply free(someArray). Now, if you malloc'd more memory and added that to someArray, then you need to walk that array and free each object.

in other words if you:

```
for(int i=0; i< whatever; ++i) {
  someArray[i] = malloc(...
}
```

Then you need to walk it again and do frees before you free someArray.

Comment: I changed my question, while you answered, sorry.

Comment: Well @Nirk gave the complete answer a bit after I told you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple 1-`free()` call:

```
free(someArray);
```

Comment: I changed my question, while you answered, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfDimensions; i++)
{
    free(somearray[i]);
    somearray[i] = NULL;
}

free(somearray);
somearray=NULL;
```

(somearray[i] = NULL) this line will break the link of each array element and finally  (somearray=NULL) will break the link to the array. These two lines will free up the array of dynamic memory and the OS allocate  this freed memory to some other process

Comment: can you please improve the post? Instead of only posing a sample code, can you try to explain the reason behind writing the code?